# Horizontal List - Evenly fill space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the following horizontal list to evenly fill the space..

https://jsfiddle.net/069bmfr0/

```
<ul class="tabs-menu ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
<li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab1')">tab1</a></li>
<li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab2')">tab2</a></li>< 
<li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab3')">tab3</a></li>
<li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab4')">tab4</a></li>                   
</ul>

.tabs-menu{text-align:justify;width:100%;background:grey;}
.tabs-menu:after{content:'';display:inline-block;width:100%;}
.tabs-menu li{display:inline-block;padding:10px;border-right:2px solid white;}
.tabs-menu a{color:white;}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "evenly fill the space"? Are there gaps in the list?

Comment: Like this example http://jsfiddle.net/9hh86/547/ but using flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 Flexbox will do that using `display:flex` in `ul` and `flex:1` in `li`, the magin is in `flex:1` which is shorthand for `flex-grow` /`flex-shrink`/`flex-basis`, so longhanded  is `flex:1 0 auto`.
Having `flex-grow:1` means it will grow evenly to its siblings .

**UPDATE**

After Op's comment

> jsfiddle.net/9hh86/547 could this be done using flexbox instead?

you can use `justify-content:space-between` in `ul`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.tabs-menu {
   
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs-menu li {
  padding:10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px;
}

.tabs-menu a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs-menu ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab1')">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab2')">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab3')">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab4')">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works great, but what if I wanted things to be evenly spaced but without any padding?

Comment: @fightstarr20 see updated answer, now instead of `padding: 10px`, you  have `padding: 10px 0`, which means only `padding` for top and bottom, no left or right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hh86/547/ could this be done using flexbox instead?

Comment: Thank you, flexbox was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I would use `flex` on the parent, and set the children to `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0` so they grow to fill the parent evenly based on the parent's width, and not the content in the `li`. Also add `text-align: center;` and remove the padding from the `ul`

```css
.tabs-menu {
  text-align: justify;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs-menu li {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs-menu a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs-menu ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab1')">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab2')">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab3')">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab4')">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to handle this is with flex:

```
.tabs-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0; // Optional, but probably desired
}

.tabs-menu li {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.tabs-menu {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: inlinea-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  flex: 1;
}

.tabs-menu a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs-menu ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab1')">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab2')">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab3')">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('tab4')">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've also created a working fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/L8vwx7xo/1/).

Hope this helps! :)